# Get redirected from URL in php

Tags: php, redirect, header

I want to know how to get the original URL from php

For example:

```
example.php
<?php

header('location:test.php');

?>
```

I want to get test.php from example.php.

Comment: You can try `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, but it's easy to fake. You can try using $_SESSION to save it.

Comment: I don't really understand what you want. With this code snippet, you will be redirected to `youdomain.com/test.php`

Comment: You should not be using relative paths when setting a location header!  This is technically invalid.  You must give the full URL.

Answer (score 3):

```
example.php
<?php

header('location:' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

?>
```

This should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Redirection with some delay say after 5 sec wait.

```
function js_redirect($url, $seconds)
{
    echo "<script language=\"JavaScript\">\n";
    echo "<!-- hide code from displaying on browsers with JS turned off\n\n";
    echo "function redirect() {\n";
    echo "window.parent.location = \"" . $url . "\";\n";
    echo "}\n\n";
    echo "timer = setTimeout('redirect()', '" . ($seconds*1000) . "');\n\n";
    echo "-->\n";
    echo "</script>\n";

    return true;
}

js_redirect("http://www.exapmle.com",5); // Redirect after 5 sec
```

Answer (score 0):

you forget to use

```
ob_start();
```

in first of your code :D

elsewhere you can use js in this case , for example :

```
echo 'javascript:window.location="http://example.com";';
```